# Is there any other reasons beside market manipulation for a penny stock declined 20% within 5 minutes to closing despites nonnegative news?

Tags: stocks, markets

Is there any other reasons beside market manipulation for a penny stock declined 20% within 5 minutes to closing despites nonnegative news? It declined so rapidly that I placed market order to sell but my broker was only able to filled 5% of my order. I feel like something is not right here. Please share your opinions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Low market depth and liquidity can be a reason for high volatility. The fact that your market order wasn't really filled is also a sign. There just wasn't any buyer in the market that are interested at the current price range. To achieve a sell, you either wait for a buyer to show up (spend time) or offer a big discount (spend money). Looks like someone chose the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Trading in penny stocks is considered dangerous, not only because the value of the underlying companies is poor and could potentially disappear any time into bankruptcy, but also because you are trading in an area where *technical market mechanisms* can influence your results significantly.

If it sits at 5 cent, the smallest possible change is 1 cent down, which results in 4 cent, and equals a *20% decline*. The percentage change is not always meaningful in these ranges.

Many people ride on that (as I did years ago); if a share hops around between 1 and 2 cents over some time, you can just buy a bunch of them, and put out a continuous high volume buy at 1 cent and a continuous high volume sell at 2 cent. Ever so often some trade comes by, and you make *100%* on each pair.